# Simplify "IF" statement in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I am creating a google sheet and currently I have a manually entered number in Column C, and then following cells with IF functions based on the value entered. I'm wondering if there's a way to simplify this.

Here's what I have in E2 for example: =IF(IF($C2>=70,35,$C2-35)<0,0,IF($C2>=70,35,$C2-35))

Then in F2: =IF(IF($C2>=105,35,$C2-70)<0,0,IF($C2>=105,35,$C2-70))

Then in G2: =IF(IF($C2>=140,35,$C2-105)<0,0,IF($C2>=140,35,$C2-105))

And so on by increments of 35.

I figure there's probably a better way to do this than just copy, paste, and adjust the numbers. What should I do instead?

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour). Please [edit](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/posts/168671/edit) your question and insert a [table](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/editing-help#tables) of sample data together with another table that shows your manually entered desired results. Also consider sharing a publicly editable sample spreadsheet. There is a [blank sheet maker](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeprZS3Al0n7JiVQIEiCi_Ad9FRXbpgB7x1-Wq6iAfdmVbWiA/viewform) that lets you share safely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These three simpler formulas get the same results as your `if()` formulas:

```
=max( 0, min(35, C2 - 35) )
=max( 0, min(35, C2 - 70) )
=max( 0, min(35, C2 - 105) )
```

To process all the rows in column `C`, automatically creating as many columns as required, without copying the formula down, use `byrow()` and `bycol()`, like this:

```
=lambda( 
  column, step, numSteps, 
  byrow( 
    column, 
    lambda( 
      value, 
      bycol( 
        sequence(1, numSteps), 
        lambda( 
          coefficient, 
          max( 
            0, 
            min( 
              step, 
              value - step * coefficient 
            ) 
          ) 
        ) 
      ) 
    ) 
  ) 
)( 
  C2:C42, 35, 5 
)
```

Comment: neat solution 

Comment: Thank you! I'm going to try to get some practice with the functions you mentioned. I appreciate the help!!